# I get this error: DatagridviewComboboxCell Value is not valid

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void StudentDetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "Select * from tbl_Branch";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConn);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Rows.Add();
            da.Fill(table);
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn GC = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            GC = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)gvStudentData.Columns["Branch"];
            GC.DataSource = table;
            GC.ValueType = typeof(string);
            GC.ValueMember = "BranchID";
            GC.DisplayMember = "Branch";
            //gvStudentData.Rows.Add();

            DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
            string query1 = "Select * from tbl_StudentDetails";
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(query1, sqlConn);
            da1.Fill(table1);
            int j = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < table1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                gvStudentData.Rows.Add();
                gvStudentData.Rows[j].Cells["USN"].Value = table1.Rows[i]["USN"].ToString();
                gvStudentData.Rows[j].Cells["FName"].Value = table1.Rows[i]["FName"].ToString();
                gvStudentData.Rows[j].Cells["MName"].Value = table1.Rows[i]["MName"].ToString();
                gvStudentData.Rows[j].Cells["LName"].Value = table1.Rows[i]["LName"].ToString();
                gvStudentData.Rows[j].Cells["Branch"].Value = table1.Rows[i]["BranchID"].ToString();
                gvStudentData.Rows[j].Cells["Semester"].Value = table1.Rows[i]["Semester"].ToString();

                j = j + 1;
            }

        }
```

I am trying to use 2 datasources in this scenario. One for the combobox column and other to display fetched data. I am getting this error on form load.

Comment: 1. Format your code properly. 2. What have you tried (debugging, isolating pain points)?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
gvStudentData.Rows[j].Cells["Branch"].Value = table1.Rows[i]["BranchID"].ToString();
```

to

```
gvStudentData.Rows[j].Cells["BranchId"].Value = table1.Rows[i]["BranchID"].ToString();
```

Comment: Column name is Branch in my grid.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the datasource assignment. It was just that there was no datasource assigned to another datagridviewcolumn.There was no error until the form load event reached its end point.

Thanks for putting efforts in solving this problem.